# Python: reorganize data and add it to dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to loop trough a csv in python. The data is positions of traffic cameras, looking something like this.

```
id,lat,lon
2001,xxx,xxx
2001,xxx,xxx
2001,xxx,xxx
2002,xxx,xxx
2002,xxx,xxx
2002,xxx,xxx
```

I want to extract the coordinates belonging to each id-number and put them in a new list, one for each id in a dictionary.

```
{21008:["61.693041701246464,17.07523578189965","61.69143482820877,17.075789632658555","61.680418586326795,17.07858434001964","61.6742753006184,17.077453196013725"]}
```

I'm fairly green at this. What would be the best method to get this done? I'm not asking for a complete solution, but a push in the right direction would be nice. I'm using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
import  csv
with open(infile) as f:
    # skip header
    next(f)
    # use reader to get all rows
    r = csv.reader(f)
    # unpack from each row
    for _id, lt, ln in r:
        # use _id as key and append lat and lon
        d[_id].append("{},{}".format(lt,ln))
print(d)
```

Or without the csv module:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
import csv
with open("in.txt") as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        _id, lt_lon = line.split(",", 1)
        d[_id].append(lt_lon.rstrip())
print(d)
```

Comment: @MartinHedström, no prob, you're welcome. If order matters you can use a `collections.OrderedDict` instead with `dict.setdefault`

Answer (score 0):

Python has the `csv` module, which even has the DictReader object, that does all this for you.

Comment: It won't create the lists required by the OP.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: true, but OP explicitely asked for a push in the right direction only. and that's what my answer does :)

Comment: I fail to see how it'd actually help though. `csv.reader()` would work better.